# is there a simple way to output to xlsx?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to output a query from a DB to a xlsx but it takes so much time to do this because there about 20,000 records to process, is there a simpler way to do this?

I know there is a way to do it for csv but im trying to avoid that, because if the records had any comma is going to take it as a another column and that would mess with the info

this is my code

```
$xlsObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xlsObj.DisplayAlerts = $false
$xlsWb = $xlsobj.Workbooks.Add(1)

$xlsObj.Visible = 0 #(visible = 1 / 0 no visible)

$xlsSh = $xlsWb.Worksheets.Add([System.Reflection.Missing]::Value, $xlsWb.Worksheets.Item($xlsWb.Worksheets.Count))
$xlsSh.Name = "QueryResults"



    $DataSetTable= $ds.Tables[0]
    Write-Output "DATA SET TABLE" $DataSetTable

[Array] $getColumnNames = $DataSetTable.Columns | SELECT *
Write-Output "COLUMN NAMES" $DataSetTable.Rows[0]
[Int] $RowHeader = 1
foreach ($ColH in $getColumnNames)
{
    $xlsSh.Cells.item(1, $RowHeader).font.bold = $true
    $xlsSh.Cells.item(1, $RowHeader) = $ColH.ColumnName
    Write-Output "Nombre de Columna"$ColH.ColumnName
    $RowHeader++
}


[Int] $rowData = 2
[Int] $colData = 1
 
foreach ($rec in $DataSetTable.Rows)
{
    foreach ($Coln in $getColumnNames)
    {
    
        $xlsSh.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
    
        $xlsSh.Cells.Item($rowData, $colData) = $rec.$($Coln.ColumnName).ToString()
        $ColData++
    }
    
    $rowData++; $ColData = 1
}


$xlsRng = $xlsSH.usedRange
[void] $xlsRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
#Se elimina la pestaña Sheet1/Hoja1.
$xlsWb.Sheets(1).Delete() #Versión 02


$xlsFile = "directory of the file"
[void] $xlsObj.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs($xlsFile)
$xlsObj.Quit()


Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 700
 While ([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xlsRng)) {''}
 While ([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xlsSh)) {''}
 While ([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xlsWb)) {''}
 While ([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xlsObj)) {''}
[gc]::collect() | Out-Null
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() | Out-Null

$oraConn.Close()
```

Comment: What does "if the records had any comma is going to take it as a another column and that would mess with the info" mean?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart .csv files are typically stored as comma delimited lists. so if his data has a comma, the file will process it as the end of a column.

Comment: That sounds like an imagined problem. See output from `[pscustomobject]@{Column1 = "string,with,commas,"; Column2 = 123}|ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation` for example, PowerShell qualifies value boundaries with quotation marks. CSV as a format is obviously loosely defined, but most CSV parsers I've encountered take quoted strings into account.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen and if the string is not quoted? i'm just trying to get ahead any scenario which i dont have to worry in xlsx

Comment: @HeberSolis It's not dependent on how the input object was defined, it'll quote any string

Comment: Check what character you get with `(Get-Culture).TextInfo.ListSeparator`. If it is NOT a comma, Excel has trouble reading it and you should use `ConvertTo-Csv` or `Export-Csv` together with either parameter `-Delimiter '<theListSeparatorCharacter>'`, OR (much easier) add switch `-UseCulture`. Then when double-clicking the csv file, Excel reads it just fine.

Comment: `ConvertTo-Csv` will quote the fields. There is no concern if the data contains a COMMA. The `-Delimiter` parameter needs to be used if a delimiter other than COMMA is desired. That is how Microsoft interprets the CSV standard.

Comment: I posted my initial question not because I didn't understand the OP, but rather to encourage the OP to write a more specific technical description of the problem instead of "take it as another column and that would mess with the info".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to avoid [CSV files], because if the records had any comma is going to take it as a another column and that would mess with the info

That's only the case if you try to construct the output format manually. Builtin commands like `Export-Csv` and `ConvertTo-Json` will automatically quote the values as necessary:

```
PS C:\> $customObject = [pscustomobject]@{ID = 1; Name = "Solis, Heber"}
PS C:\> $customObject

ID Name
-- ----
 1 Solis, Heber

PS C:\> $customObject |ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
"ID","Name"
"1","Solis, Heber"
```

Notice, in the example above, how:

- The string value assigned to `$customObject.Name` does *not* contain any quotation marks, but
- In the output from `ConvertTo-Csv` we see values and headers clearly enclosed in quotation marks

PowerShell automatically enumerates the row data when you pipe a `[DataTable]` instance, so creating a CSV might (depending on the contents) be as simple as:

```
$ds.Tables[0] |Export-Csv table_out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

#### What if you want TAB-separated values (or any other non-comma separator)?

The `*-Csv` commands come with a `-Delimiter` parameter to which you can pass a user-defined separator:

```
# This produces semicolon-separated values
$data |Export-Csv -Path output.csv -Delimiter ';'
```

---

I usually try and refrain from recommending specific modules libraries, but if you insist on writing to XSLX I'd suggest checking out [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.0.1) (don't let the name fool you, it does more than import from excel, including exporting and formatting data from PowerShell -> XSLX)

Comment: Plus you could always use `-Delimiter` to use anything else but a `,`